# Maximum sending rate exceeded. SMTP 454 error

Tags: php, email

While sending emails using PHP mailer. It gives following error.

> Email not sent. SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA
>   END command failed Detail: Throttling failure: Maximum sending rate
>   exceeded. SMTP code: 454.

```
{
$email = "// 200 emails// ";
$new = explode(", ", $email);
foreach($new as $email_list) {
$mail->addBCC($email_list);
}
```

Comment: That sounds like an SMTP server configuration matter, you'll need to talk to your administrator. This will be about the total number of emails you are sending, probably not about the number of bcc's on an individual email.

Comment: your sending your emails too fast.  `Maximum sending rate exceeded` - if you don't control the SMTP server, you'll have to probably send them slower or find a different SMTP. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ISP setting 
usually is setting are:

- a limit to mail send for an interval of time
- a limit to the number of receiver for a singol e-mail.